# Making polygons from lines (polyline to polygon) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to remember how to do polygons from lines, I remember it was a very simple procedure. have a layer of lines intersecting or touching, use the tool and voila, qgis took the lines layer  and created a layer of polygons  with the spaces between the lines. very simple tool with Polygonize here http://confound.me.uk/maps/ppv4.pdf

However today I try, I can not get a good result. For this exercise I made a layer of lines with different shapes as you can see below.

[image]

A= it is a single line that does not close (in the table object id 0)

B= a square with lines in, that joined to form a single object (in table object id 1)

C= a triangle made of different lines that are touching, for this I used the snapping tool (in the table objects id 2,3,4)

This is the result of: vectorial-> Geometry Tools -> lines to polygon

[image]

As observed the tool close the object A to forms a good polygon (table object id 0), object B is formed with errors and under a single polygon (table object id 1) and the C object (the triangle) is completely ignored

This is the result of: processing-> vectorial geometry -> lines to polygons

[image]

As observed the tool close the object A to forms a good polygon (table object id 0), object B is formed with errors and under a single polygon (table object id 1) and the C object (the triangle) is completely ignored

This is the result of processing-> vectorial geometry -> poligonize

[image]

the poligonize tool gives a different result, only a general polygon shape without taking into account the interior lines of the B object and the table is filled with the area and perimeter of this.

As you can see the results are not what I expected, as I recall it was very easy to make and very good results were obtained and usually had to make small adjustments to the polygons.

and I read this answer from 2014:

[Making polygon from intersecting lines in QGIS using Polygonize or similar?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85452/make-a-polygon-from-intersecting-lines-in-qgis-using-polygonize-or-similar)

with a very similar problem where the possibility that the tool is BROKEN , however I dont know if this will be the case **or I doing something wrong with the tool**

QGIS: 2.14.3 
Installer: standalone QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.3-1-Setup-x86_64
OS: Windows 10 64bits (1115 10586.318)